# libSTARK TinyRAM private inputs (Zero-knowledge proofs)

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I am looking into [libSTARK](https://github.com/elibensasson/libSTARK) and specifically TinyRAM and I cannot find out how to provide private inputs in a TinyRAM program. As private input I mean a variable that only the prover knows; i.e. the verifier has zero-knowledge of it.

In the DNA profile match (DPM) example that is described in ["Scalable, transparent, and post-quantum secure computational
integrity"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/046.pdf), both the DNA fingerprint database and the suspect's fingerprint are supposed private. However, the DPM example is not implemented in TinyRAM and there is no TinyRAM example with private inputs. Also, by looking at the code, I could not find a command or a way to "hide" the value of a specific variable from the verifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank Jonathan Bootle who helped me answer my question.

TinyRAM has two tapes, the primary and the auxiliary. The `Primary Input Tape` is used for public inputs while the `Auxiliary Input Tape` is used to provide private inputs.